# How to export a list of list to a set of excel files

Tags: r

I have a list of list lst2, which looks like this:

[image]

I would like to out this list to Excel:

1. Each sublist in one Excel file;
2. Each df in the sublist will be a sheet in excel workbook
3. Add filter on the 2nd row of each sheet;

For example, we will have a file call `101-01-101.xlsx`, and in that file, we will have two sheets: `Demographics` and `DiseaseStatus`, and we will have a filter added on the 2nd row of each sheet. We will have 5 Excel files at the end.

How can I auto generate those files without doing it one by one? It seems like `write.xlsx` can not add format to the output. probaly we have to use `library(openxlsx)`. Any one has any idea on how to handle this type work?

The sample list can be build using codes:

```
lst2<-list(`101-01-101` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-01-101"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1953-07-07"), SEX = c("Gender", 
"Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-01-101"), DSDT = c("DS Date", "2016-03-14"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))), `101-02-102` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-02-102"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1963-07-02"), SEX = c("Gender", 
"Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-02-102"), DSDT = c("DS Date", "2017-04-04"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))), `101-03-103` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-03-103"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1940-09-11"), SEX = c("Gender", 
"Male")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
"101-03-103"), DSDT = c("DS Date", NA), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
"UN-UNK-2015")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), `101-04-104` = list(Demographics = structure(list(
    SubjectID = c("Subject ID", "101-04-104"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", 
    "1955-12-31"), SEX = c("Gender", "Male")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(
    SubjectID = c("Subject ID", "101-04-104"), DSDT = c("DS Date", 
    "2016-05-02"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), `104-05-201` = list(
    Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
    "104-05-201"), BRTHDTC = c("Birthday", "1950-12-04"), SEX = c("Gender", 
    "Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("Subject ID", 
    "104-05-201"), DSDT = c("DS Date", "2018-07-06"), DSDT_P = c("DS Date Prob", 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by having a filter added to the second row, but I hope the following code helps you.

```
saveFolder <- "someDirectory"
if(!dir.exists(saveFolder)) dir.create(saveFolder)
xlsxNames <- paste0(names(lst2),".xlsx")
xlsxPaths <- file.path(saveFolder,xlsxNames)

for(k in 1:length(lst2)) {
  print(paste0("Processing ",k, " of ", length(lst2)))
  currentSavePath <- xlsxPaths[k]
  tablesToSave <- lst2[[k]]
  sheetNames <- names(tablesToSave)
  for(i in 1:length(tablesToSave)) {
    if(!file.exists(currentSavePath)) {
      #File does not exist, create it by writing the firdst sheet
      xlsx::write.xlsx(x = tablesToSave[[i]], file = currentSavePath, sheetName = sheetNames[i])
    } else {
      #File does exist, hence we have already written something in there, must use append
      xlsx::write.xlsx(x = tablesToSave[[i]], file = currentSavePath, sheetName = sheetNames[i], 
                       append = TRUE)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Couple more question,: it seems like there is row number in the output. how can I remove that? As for filter, I mean sth like`addFilter(wb, sheet = "Con Meds Complete", rows =3, cols = 1:dim(CM_Master_tab)[2])
addStyle(wb,sheet = "Con Meds Complete", style = tableheaderStyle, rows = 3, cols =1:dim(CM_Master_tab)[2], stack = TRUE)`. I know how to do it on single table, but not sure how to do it with this situation.